# INSERT/DELETE examples in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql-server, many-to-many

I have three tables, Users, Roles, and a junction UserRoles.

```
Users       UserRoles         Roles
=======     =============     =========
UserId      UserId            RoleId
Username    RoleId            Role
Firstname   Date
```

My tables are joined like this:

```
Users.UserId -> UserRoles.UserId
Roles.RoleId -> UserRoles.RoleId
```

Basically, what I am looking for is an simple example that shows:

1. How to INSERT in UserRoles a UserId and a RoleId for a specific Username with a specific Role.
2. Delete a role for a specific Username

I managed to make a simple select on Roles for a specific Username like so:

```
SELECT 
    dbo.Roles.Role 
FROM dbo.Roles 
INNER JOIN dbo.UserRoles 
    ON dbo.Roles.RoleId = dbo.UserRoles.RoleId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Users 
    ON dbo.UserRoles.UserId = dbo.Users.UserId 
WHERE (Username = @Username)
```

Comment: Are you sure your select query is working, I doubt? Check "WHERE" clause in Select query.

Comment: yes it is working "@Username" is a parameter from my .NET code. Can be used like this also: WHERE (Username = 'John Doe'). Thanks

Comment: Not possible to insert into UserRoles based on current table design. Since when I insert User in Users table there's no relation between Users and Roles. I can insert UserID into UserRoles but not RoleID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To INSERT in UserRoles a UserId and a RoleId for a specific Username with a specific Role, you need to redesign your tables such that the User table has a foreign key to the Roles tables as follows:

```
Users       UserRoles         Roles
=======     =============     =========
UserId      UserId            RoleId
Username    RoleId            Role
Firstname   Date
RoleId
```

Then insert as follows:

```
insert into dbo.UserRoles (UserId, RoleId, [Date])
select
    u.UserId,
    r.RoleId,
    getdate() as [Date]
from dbo.Users u
inner join dbo.Roles r
   on r.RoleId = u.RoleId
   and u.Username = @Username
```

To delete a role for a specific Username with the above schema:

```
delete r
from dbo.Roles r
inner join dbo.User u
   on r.RoleId = u.Roleid
where u.Username = @Username
```

**EDIT**: Another solution suggested by @sidux

```
DELETE ur 
FROM dbo.UserRoles ur 
JOIN dbo.Roles r 
    ON r.RoleId = ur.RoleId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Users u 
    ON ur.UserId = u.UserId 
WHERE (Username = @Username);
```

Comment: SELECT ... INTO statement creates new table. So this works only for initial insert. Use INSERT INTO ... SELECT

Comment: @chiridam, thanks for your response and time! When i execute the delete query i get this error : Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_UsersRoles_Roles". The conflict occurred in database "UsersRoles", table "dbo.UserRoles", column 'RoleId'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @Stefan The error means that you have data in the `dbo.UsersRoles` table that references the data you are trying to delete. You would need to either drop and recreate the constraints or delete the data that the Foreign Key references by way of deleting every row from "child" table `dbo.UsersRoles` and after it delete all rows from "parent" table `dbo.Roles`.

Comment: do: DELETE ur
FROM dbo.UserRoles  ur
JOIN dbo.Roles r
r.RoleId = ur.RoleId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Users  u
    ON ur.UserId = u.UserId 
WHERE (Username = @Username);

Answer (score 0):

you can use Merge and write everything in proc.Don't forget to Test and give error details here.

I am using @Flg because you may need Update Statement also.in that case it will be helpful .

```
Declare @Flg char(1)='D' -- D/I/U

Declare @Username varchar(50)

Merge into UserRoles  as trg
using(Select
    u.UserId,
    r.RoleId,
    getdate() as [Date]
from dbo.Users u
inner join dbo.Roles r
   on r.RoleId = u.RoleId
   and u.Username = @Username)src
on trg.UserId=src.UserId and trg.RoleId=src.RoleId
when not matched and @Flg='I' THen
insert values(src.UserId,src.RoleId,[Date])
When matched and  @Flg='D' THen
Delete ;
```